# How to edit automatically generated code by netbeans desing UI?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have this Afficheur java class in my project (its a DrawingPanel) which takes a MainWindow object in parameter. MainWindow is essentially a swing UI which Netbeans automatically generated code for as I designed it with their desing tool.
In order for it to work I have to edit this generated code by Netbeans and add 'this' in parameter to Afficheur when I create a new Afficheur (see line 85), which only is possible when I edit the code in notepad.

This method makes my code work but as soon as I try to modify the UI with the netbeans design tool the whole thing messes up. I know this is the issue because I tried removing 'this' and then modifying my UI and then adding 'this' back and everything worked fine. Its like netbeans can't generate code properly when I have modified its code. Any Idea on how I can resolve this issue?

[image: Generated code with the added 'this']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to the design tab and then right click on the item you want to change the code of and then click customize code (or something like that, i don't remember correctly) and edit the code.